# Recent Facebook API Change?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm encountering a new error when I try to iterate through a user's "Likes" using the Facebook Javascript API.

Right now I can get 300 "Likes" total (12 pages worth of data when limited to 25 results / page). This just started happening today, last week I was able to iterate through all pages I "Like" using the following code:

```
 FB.api('me/likes', function(res) {
      iteratePages(res);
 });
```

res responds with an array of 25 pages that I (the user) "Like" and a paging attribute that contains a "next" page that I would navigate to after parsing out all of the likes. Normally this continues until res.paging.next is undefined at which point I would store some data and whatnot.

I know I have over 800 liked pages but I'm only getting 300 results before the API calls just stop with this error/stack trace:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'next' of undefined
at Object.iteratePages [as success] (http://mysitethatisstillinbeta.beta/js/dashboard.js:77:20)
at c (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js:4:26036)
at Object.p.fireWith [as resolveWith] (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js:4:26840)
at k (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js:6:14258)
at XMLHttpRequest.r (http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js:6:18646)
```

Any thoughts? I'm pretty stumped on this one, it's very frustrating.

Comment: We had some similar hikups two days ago, I guess it's just a Facebook bug. Hope they will solve this soon.

Comment: I believe they changed the API, I'll answer my question below. Let me know if you figured out a different solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the paging attribute doesn't exist on the last item anymore, there are a couple solutions for this.

1st and best, **switch the detection mechanism** from checking if response.paging.next exists to checking the length of data returned by the query:

```
if response.data.length > 0
    do whatever you're doing
    then call response.paging.after OR response.paging.next to turn the page
else
    you're at the end of your list
```

This is what the responses look like when they contain data:

```
{
  "data": [ ... 
],
"paging": {
  "cursors": {
    "after": "some cursor", 
    "before": "another cursor"
}, 
"previous": "some addr"
}}}
```

And when they don't:

```
{ "data": [] }
```

There might be a bug or change that's limiting the number of pages per query, I think this is what was causing the problem. **Increasing the number of results returned counters the limited number of  pages** (I increased from 25/page to 1000), hope others find this useful!